# How to avoid the redirect output sign">"being taken as command line arguments(in a shortcut maybe)

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, shortcut

I'm not able to redirect standard output to the file by calling the shortcut on Windows.

it works directly `"exe.exe 1 2 1 4 5 6 7 >> log.txt"`,the log file is generated successfully.

I assume that the ">>" sign is taken as an argument while using the shortcut.lnk, Thus it does not generate log.txt

how can I start the command properly or modify the program to achieve what I want?

here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string acc = "";
            string pass = "";
            string EmailEnabled = "";
            string smtpServer = "";
            string sender = "";
            string smtpAuth = "";
            string receiver = "";
            if (args.Length == 7)
            {
                acc = args[0];
                pass = args[1];
                EmailEnabled = args[2];
                smtpServer = args[3];
                sender = args[4];
                smtpAuth = args[5];
                receiver = args[6];
            }
            else if (args[2] == "0")
            {
                acc = args[0];
                pass = args[1];
                EmailEnabled = args[2];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("command line arguments are wrong");
                return;
            }
}
```

Screenshots:

[in this way,the">"is taken as an argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z13y1.png)

[in another way,the">" funtions normal as redirect sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUrik.png)

Comment: whats your problem exactly?

Comment: btw, you second else if block will potentially throw indexoutofrange exception when one or no arguments passed

Comment: reply to qwr: In the shortcut .lnk file ,the ">"sign is taken as arguments,not as redirect sign

Comment: I see. you mean you trying to call you executable through shortcut with arguments right?

Comment: YES.Actually i am tring to create a "schtask" in windows system, the way it excutes a programme is same as the way through a shortcut.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/29569/how-to-add-command-line-options-to-shortcut

Comment: was it helpful?

Comment: sorry, the web shows how to add arguments, i have added arguments and I 'd like to add the redirect sign extra... i have posted 2 screenshot to describe my question

Comment: try with "start \b "

Comment: Start a new instance of CMD.exe and pass the string containing the >> as an argument to it using `/C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the question is related to Windows more than C#
so to redirect shortcut

@Flydog57's comment

```
cmd /c "file_shortcut.lnk" bla bla bla  >out.txt
```

---

coming on C#:
you can make 8th argument output file and redirect the standard output
following this:
[console.setout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=net-5.0)
probably something like this:

```
   using (var writer = args.Length>7? new StreamWriter(args[7]) : new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))
        { 
                Console.SetOut(writer); 
               //all codes inside
        }
```